# EDI Hex Character Issues

Tags: java, hex, filemaker

So we're exporting records from a Filemaker Pro database and submitting those files to our vendor via EDI, but their system cannot accept our files because of some really wonky ".." (Hex 0B) characters that show up at the beginning of every new line in the text document.

I've read that there are issues with how Filemaker Pro exports their files and because of that these Hex 0B characters can't be deleted beforehand, [from within Filemaker](http://forums.filemaker.com/posts/7faeb91c60). I have a limited understanding of Java, would there be an adequate Java based run-time solution that could be created to fix this problem?

I've tried exporting the text file in question in every available export method, including .mer, .csv, .tab, etc, with every combination of output file character set available for each export type, some create even more issues with hidden characters. I ended up settling on .tab (ASCII [DOS]) as it had the lowest amount of residual information, but I still need to get rid of these 0B characters for our EDI integration partner to be able to accept our files without any issue.

EDIT: Added more information for clarity.

Comment: "*I've read that there are issues with how Filemaker Pro exports their files*" I've never heard of such issues - a link perhaps? How exactly are you exporting: what format, what charset?

Comment: I should add that xOb is a vertical tab character; you *will* get those when you export as csv or tab-delimited, **if** you have carriage returns in the exported field/s; the carriage return is reserved as record delimiter in these formats.

Comment: Updated the post. I'm just confused as to how I'm going to get this data to export, as I've tried exporting the field directly, I've tried exporting records, only selecting that field... I'm kind of stumped.

Comment: You are not explaining what exactly "this data" is. Please post an example of a record (what fields are you exporting, what do they contain, are you exporting multiple records, etc.) and the **exact** desired output. Otherwise this will not move forward. BTW, the answer given by FMI support in the thread you linked to is rather pathetic, but that is hardly surprising.

Answer (score 0):

The hex value "0B" in ascii is a vertical tab.

[This chart](http://www.columbia.edu/~kermit/ascii.html) is a good reference point for figuring out the hex values for specific ascii values and vice versa.

Getting the vertical tab out of the text field is a bit irritating but do-able. I had to do it for a series of documents we imported into filemaker as text and then moved to a postgresql database. What I did was the following:

- Downloaded the free application [Hex Fiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) (this app allows you to enter text and see it's hex value or hex and see it's text equivalent)
- Enter the value `0B` into the left panel of Hex Fiend (the hex side)
- Click into the right panel of Hex Fiend (the text side) and then click the menu command **Edit -> Select All** to select the entire contents of the text side and then **Edit -> Copy** to copy the contents (your vertical tab text character) to the clipboard
- In FileMaker, create a script with script step:

  `Set Field[myTable::myField ; Substitute ( myTable::myField ; "*pasteVerticalTabCharacterHere*" ; "" )]`
- Paste your vertical tab character in between the first set of quotes of the substitute function

  - Note that when you do this, your substitute function will probably break to two lines
- Leave the second set of quotes in the substitute function blank

When you fire this script on a record that contains vertical tabs in `myfield` it will substitute them for a blank string `""`. You could also change the substitute function to switch the vertical tab out with a carriage return like so:

```
Set Field[myTable::myField ; Substitute ( myTable::myField ; "*pasteVerticalTabCharacterHere*" ; ¶ )]
```

If you have a number of records that need this set field step run on you could create a script that loops through all of the records and fires this step.

You could also do it the quick and dirty way of:

- Show all records that need to be cleaned
- Click into the field to be cleaned
- From the Records menu, select `Replace Field Contents`
- Enter the substitute calculation above as the replace calculation
- Hit replace

This will go through and clean the vertical tabs out of all of the records in one shot.

In the end, if you have a particular field or fields that you know will be likely to have vertical tabs in them, I would suggest putting an auto-enter calculation on the fields that contain a modified version of the substitute calculation above:

```
Substitute ( Self ; "*pasteVerticalTabCharacterHere*" ; "" )
```

This way, whenever you import records into the table that contain vertical tabs, the vertical tab character is cleaned out automatically.

I should also note that hexfiend is a mac app. I think on a windows computer you can just type the vertical tab character out by pressing `control+K`, but I haven't tried it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am afraid you are missing the point here: the vertical tab characters are **not** in the field; they are added during export, as a replacement for the carriage returns that *are* in the field. BTW, if you ever do get a vertical tab into a field, getting it out is rather trivial using `Substitute ( Yourfield ; Char (11) ; "" )`.